# How can I update an Angular controller after an AJAX API call?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax

I'm creating a weather forecast app, using ng-repeat to iterate on my forecast.dayArray to create the different days in the page.

The issue is that the controller used to fill in the data in each "day" isn't being updated with the information that is parsed from the ajax API call. Instead, it just keeps whatever value it was initialized with.

```
//Initialize
var app = angular.module("weather", []);

app.controller("ForecastController", function(){
    this.array = ['a','b','c'];
});

ajaxCall(){
success: function(){
     app.controller.array.push('d'); //Doesn't seem to work
};
```

You can see the code in its entirety here: [My Codepen](http://codepen.io/Vercaelus/pen/KroWJa?editors=0010)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, `app.controller` is a function that is used to set up a new controller, so in this line:

> `app.controller.array.push('d');`

`app.controller` is not a reference to your `"ForecastController"`.

A simple way to fix this would be to make the AJAX call from within the controller, facilitated by the `$http` service:

```
app.controller("ForecastController", ["http", function ($http) {
    this.array = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

    $http
        .get(...)
        .then(function (response) {
            this.array.push('d');
        });
}]);
```

While this will work, it is typically considered better practice to separate the data fetching into its own service and inject that new service into your controller.

Comment: Alright, I believe I understand. But, isn't there an easier way? I had assumed (incorrectly, perhaps) that I could just access any controller variables through dot notation, and the changes would be reflected instantly. Is it not possible to change my values at any random point, and have those changes reflected in the DOM immediately?

Comment: You certainly can change them at any point, and they will be reflected in the DOM, but you usually wouldn't try to reach into the internal implementation of how Angular stores the controller. If, for example, you wanted to trigger that AJAX call from a button press, you might attach an `ng-click` in your markup that calls a method on your controller to actually perform the AJAX call.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use `$http` service. You can either inject this at your controller level, or abstract it with a factory/service.

```
var app = angular.module("weather", []);

app.controller("ForecastController", ['$http', function($http) {
  this.array = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

  $http.get('someURLhere').then(function(response) {
    //http call success!
    this.array.push('d');
  }, function(error) {
    //error here! handle the error
    alert(error.data)
  })
}]);
```

You can read on how to use the `$http` service [here](https://www.google.com.sg/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=angular%20http).

Answer (score -2):

It is not necessary  to use the $http service, you still can update the scope from out of angular using $scope.$apply